# LIBSVM: output of svm-predict is all 0 even though I'm using the test data which was used for training

Tags: svm, libsvm

I'm using libsvm to perform binary classification. I used [easy.py](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/blob/master/tools/easy.py)  for training which is included in [libsvm](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm) library. After running easy.py, it showed the following in stdout.

```
Cross validation...
Best c=8192.0, g=8.0 CV rate=93.3155
Training...
Output model: parameters.data.model
```

The svm model file is generated, and the accuracy looks good. So I used svm-predict (executable file) to see if the generated SVM really classifies data. Here, the test data I used is exactly the same as the one I used for the training.

However all test data is classified as label 0. and the accuracy shown is really low.
The command I executed is something like following.

```
python easy.py parameters.data
# model and scale files are generated

./svm-predict parameters.data parameters.data.model svmpredict_output.log
# svmpredict_output.log is all 0
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, sorry. My stupid mistake.

The svm used scaled dataset for training, but I was using un-scaled dataset for test data.

```
./svm-predict parameters.data.scale parameters.data.model svmpredict_output.log
```

Like above, everything works well. (extension like *.scale, *.data should be the same if you're using easy.py)